# Can we use Highcharts with React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-native

Currently I am using Highcharts for my web app, but now I am building an android app using react-native. Will Highcharts work with React-native.

Comment: There is [an official Highcharts article about using Highcharts with React](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react), so maybe you will get some more info there.

Comment: Looks like page is not available now

Comment: **Most of the answers here looks outdated.** Please refer to my answer in 2019.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HighCharts works with the DOM. You cannot use HighCharts or charting libraries that depend on the DOM directly in React Native, but you can use charting libraries in a [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) with React Native. I have not use High Charts specifically, but have used other charting libraries with WebView and it works great.

Comment: Thanks @Nader. But I am still finding it difficult to understand how to render this chart inside webview. I am using Highcharts npm package but still could not figure out how to use it with webview

Comment: That qualifies as a different question, not related with this. I suggest you accept @Nader's answer if it fits and create a separate question for directions to using HighCharts in WebView.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use this component to send the config json to the componente and it will be displayed

https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts

Answer (score 2):

Two main ways you can utilise Highcharts in React Native app are :

1. [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) component. I used this technique on other platforms (Appcelerator Titanium) as well.
2. **[Official](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/highcharts-react-native-wrapper/)** minimal Highcharts wrapper for React : [highcharts-react-native](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native).
   As of now pre-requisite for this are:

   - node 11.2+
   - npm 6.7.0+ or similar package manager
   - React 16.4+
   - React native 0.59.3+

To install:

```
npm install @highcharts/highcharts-react-native
```

> **NOTE:** There are other **un-official** wrappers as well like [react-native-highcharts](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts) but I have not used them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module:
 [react-native-highcharts](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts).

It works using the web engine on Android or iOS and the Highcharts JavaScript module to render dynamic charts.

Example:

```
<ChartView style={{height:300}} config={conf}></ChartView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the ChartView component : originWhitelist={['']}

Example:

```
<ChartView style={{height:300}} config={conf} originWhitelist={['']}></ChartView>
```